# How do I do this with Css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I can't put the line inside the box.
When I tried 'border-left' it was like this because I used 'border radius' How can I do it?

```css
.box-input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-left: 9px solid black;
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-input"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: This gives us none information. Please provide your attempts, and your current code. HTML and CSS

Comment: I am giving immediately

Comment: .box-input{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-left: 9px solid black;
    box-shadow: -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

Comment: use a background-gradient, it will not curve on te edge.

Answer (score 2):

from my comment

> use a background-gradient, it will not curve on the edge

```css
.box-input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #a3befa 9px, transparent 9px);
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-input"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
.inner {
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  background:yellow;
  height:200px;
  width:500px;
  border-radius:25px;
}
.outer {
  border-radius:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Some text ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This layout is already in the question description.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css `pseudo` class. In my solution I used **::before**

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 450px;
    font-style: italic;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px -12px;
}

.wrapper::before {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    background: #8ac1e8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
p.message {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.bottom_info_wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
span.user_name {
    color: #444444;
}
.bottom_info {
    color: #6d6d6d;
}
span.time {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="message"> Make a drink and we'll tell you where you'll meet your soulmate
        </p>
    <div class="bottom_info_wrap">
        <span class="user_name">Carl Johnson</span>
        <div class="bottom_info">
            <span class="date">September 26, 2020 </span>
            <span class="time">1 min</span>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are making border-radius: 20px that's mean your border-left width should be 20px but your border-left width is less then border-radius.

see the sample

```css
.box-input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  border-left: 20px solid #A3BEFA;
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-input"></div>
```

if you want to use border-left css property then you have to use same pixel at border-radius and border-left-width otherwise you can do it by css linear-gradient background or pseudo-element after, before way.

for more details about border css here you can follow
[MDN border css tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Thanks.